# How to go 2 layers deep reverse relations inside django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm using a single User model for authentication and creating multiple "type" accounts using the User model. Every type has a different dashboard so different things to show.

```
Organization
-> Teacher
    -> Student
```

Q - I want to list the teachers and their corresponding students when inside a organization account ? It is a listView so I want to know how would I use revere relations to list all the students under specific teachers from an Organization account ?

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...


class Organization(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='superAdmin')
    ...

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='faculty')
    super_admin_id = models.ForeignKey(
        SuperAdmin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='faculty')
    ...


class Student(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    faculty_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='student')
    ...
```

If there's any advice on how I can improve the existing model schema, I'd like to know that as well.

Comment: Hi! Can you show all the related models? How is student related to a teacher?

Comment: @BrianD, The student has a fk with a teacher. My bad, I put out the wrong name of the teacher model. Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the teachers along with their students (in two db hits) like this:

```
teachers = Teacher.objects.filter(
    user_id__superAdmin=request.user.superAdmin
).prefetch_related('student')

for teacher in teachers:
    print(f'Teacher: {teacher.pk}')
    for student in teacher.student.all():
        print(f'Student: {student.pk}')
```

**EDIT**:

You can also [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) per teacher the number of students assigned to them so:

```
teachers = Teacher.objects.filter(
    user_id__superAdmin=request.user.superAdmin
).annotate(num_students=Count('student'))

for teacher in teachers:
    print(f'Teacher {teacher.pk} has {teacher.num_students} students')
```

Comment: This works fine. But what I want is the count of students

Comment: Ok updated. Your question did say `how would I use revere relations to *list* all the students under specific teachers`

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks